# Convert json to Object

Tags: java, json, linkedin-j

I have to convert this josn to object

```
{
  "_count": 10,
  "_start": 0,
  "_total": 22,
  "values": [
    {
      "isCommentable": true,
      "isLikable": true,
      "isLiked": false,
      "numLikes": 0,
      "timestamp": 1372172949945,
      "updateComments": {"_total": 0},
      "updateContent": {
        "company": {
          "id": 3858,
          "name": "Informatica"
        },
        "companyJobUpdate": {
          "action": {"code": "created"},
          "job": {
            "company": {
              "id": 3858,
              "name": "Informatica"
            },
            "description": "Our Company Informatica Corporation is the world\u2019s number one independent provider of data...",
            "id": 6184265,
            "locationDescription": "Redwood City, Ca.",
            "position": {"title": "Sr. Software Engineer, Cloud UI Development"},
            "siteJobRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/jobs?viewJob=&jobId=6184265"}
          }
        }
      },
      "updateKey": "UNIU-c3858-5755310492683890688-FOLLOW_CMPY",
      "updateType": "CMPY"
    },
    {
      "isCommentable": true,
      "isLikable": true,
      "isLiked": false,
      "numLikes": 0,
      "timestamp": 1372167698007,
      "updateComments": {"_total": 0},
      "updateContent": {
        "company": {
          "id": 3858,
          "name": "Informatica"
        },
        "companyJobUpdate": {
          "action": {"code": "created"},
          "job": {
            "company": {
              "id": 3858,
              "name": "Informatica"
            },
            "description": "Our Company Informatica Corporation is the world\u2019s number one independent provider of data...",
            "id": 6182826,
            "locationDescription": "San Francisco Bay Area",
            "position": {"title": "Senior Business Analyst, EDM (Finance, HR, IT) "},
            "siteJobRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/jobs?viewJob=&jobId=6182826"}
          }
        }
      },
      "updateKey": "UNIU-c3858-5755288491688734720-FOLLOW_CMPY",
      "updateType": "CMPY"
    },
    {
      "isCommentable": true,
      "isLikable": true,
      "isLiked": false,
      "numLikes": 0,
      "timestamp": 1371832207516,
      "updateComments": {"_total": 0},
      "updateContent": {
        "company": {
          "id": 3858,
          "name": "Informatica"
        },
        "companyJobUpdate": {
          "action": {"code": "created"},
          "job": {
            "company": {
              "id": 3858,
              "name": "Informatica"
            },
            "description": "Our Company Informatica Corporation is the world's number one independent provider of data...",
            "id": 6152085,
            "locationDescription": "Albany, New York",
            "position": {"title": "Territory Sales Manager State & Local"},
            "siteJobRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/jobs?viewJob=&jobId=6152085"}
          }
        }
      },
      "updateKey": "UNIU-c3858-5753881315355156480-FOLLOW_CMPY",
      "updateType": "CMPY"
    },
    {
      "isCommentable": true,
      "isLikable": true,
      "isLiked": false,
      "likes": {
        "_count": 3,
        "_start": 0,
        "_total": 39,
        "values": [
          {"person": {
            "firstName": "Vinod",
            "headline": "ERP & BI Technical Consultant at vtelebyte",
            "id": "dEelzutg-L",
            "lastName": "Kulkarni"
          }},
          {"person": {
            "firstName": "Tyler",
            "headline": "Eastern Region Account Manager \u2013 Healthcare Enterprise Sales at Informatica",
            "id": "In-enLjocC",
            "lastName": "Stowell",
            "pictureUrl": "http://m3.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_OVJogBAzbz8_h7C2YUOzgqXF5tLG2712yZDvgqnvsBA-1IXutpd61NGUwp5j7e-h0JRqtPe6y4h_"
          }},
          {"person": {
            "firstName": "Akash",
            "headline": "Student at Sit tumkur",
            "id": "DVO4M4BsBd",
            "lastName": "Ct"
          }}
        ]
      },
      "numLikes": 39,
      "timestamp": 1371752994586,
      "updateComments": {
        "_count": 3,
        "_start": 4,
        "_total": 7,
        "values": [
          {
            "comment": "Congratulations!",
            "id": 146156504,
            "person": {
              "apiStandardProfileRequest": {
                "headers": {
                  "_total": 1,
                  "values": [{
                    "name": "x-li-auth-token",
                    "value": "name:uFPj"
                  }]
                },
                "url": "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/7sXH5PNQLW"
              },
              "firstName": "Balaguru",
              "headline": "System Analyst at CSS Corp",
              "id": "7sXH5PNQLW",
              "lastName": "Velu",
              "pictureUrl": "http://m3.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_SmdaAVwIqnvZH8Agfw4jAMHsNNheHLKgfWjlAMwVwBqZcTbj3eJGxJ0qsp8BwGlluSIrOOzgCeBn",
              "siteStandardProfileRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=262541641&authType=name&authToken=uFPj&trk=api*a278759*s286422*"}
            },
            "sequenceNumber": 4,
            "timestamp": 1371971276000
          },
          {
            "comment": "Congratulations!",
            "id": 146432622,
            "person": {
              "apiStandardProfileRequest": {
                "headers": {
                  "_total": 1,
                  "values": [{
                    "name": "x-li-auth-token",
                    "value": "name:tK07"
                  }]
                },
                "url": "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/8COYAVTJGV"
              },
              "firstName": "Anna",
              "headline": "Childcare at self-employed",
              "id": "8COYAVTJGV",
              "lastName": "Pace",
              "pictureUrl": "http://m3.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_JE55fCew3yWGwYPkRec9f3wLTVRhwZ_kUSlVf3JVYyfrNpNXvuvWTTSq7cU0HxCe4WbUhQFJRrV3",
              "siteStandardProfileRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=98156615&authType=name&authToken=tK07&trk=api*a278759*s286422*"}
            },
            "sequenceNumber": 5,
            "timestamp": 1372104289000
          },
          {
            "comment": "Congrats",
            "id": 146787859,
            "person": {
              "apiStandardProfileRequest": {
                "headers": {
                  "_total": 1,
                  "values": [{
                    "name": "x-li-auth-token",
                    "value": "name:HYHO"
                  }]
                },
                "url": "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/vyo4Vsg5ne"
              },
              "firstName": "Hariharan",
              "headline": "IT Engineer at CMC Ltd",
              "id": "vyo4Vsg5ne",
              "lastName": "Radhakrishnan",
              "pictureUrl": "http://m3.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_0hOv4PJYb6189IW8xTJE4rZOwQN29DW8jkoo4AdiNh8pdWYhP6aMnlgD5wq1voeuOipwcnBko-7W",
              "siteStandardProfileRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=118057806&authType=name&authToken=HYHO&trk=api*a278759*s286422*"}
            },
            "sequenceNumber": 6,
            "timestamp": 1372224728000
          }
        ]
      },
      "updateContent": {
        "company": {
          "id": 3858,
          "name": "Informatica"
        },
        "companyStatusUpdate": {"share": {
          "comment": "Congratulations to Informatica's CFO Earl Fry for being named the Best CFO in Software for the fourth consecutive year by Institutional Investor Magazine! Read more here: http://bit.ly/1awY72V",
          "content": {
            "eyebrowUrl": "http://www.linkedin.com/share?viewLink=&sid=s5753549213216563203&url=http%3A%2F%2Flnkd%2Ein%2F665mpD&urlhash=oeve&uid=5753549072199860224",
            "shortenedUrl": "http://lnkd.in/665mpD",
            "submittedImageUrl": "http://image-store.slidesharecdn.com/6451ffa0-d9d7-11e2-8c62-22000aa5108a-large.jpg",
            "submittedUrl": "http://image-store.slidesharecdn.com/6451ffa0-d9d7-11e2-8c62-22000aa5108a-large.jpg",
            "thumbnailUrl": "https://media.licdn.com/media-proxy/ext?w=80&h=100&hash=ddfdrIOJw0RI3h7ydxxWFvK1F6E%3D&url=http%3A%2F%2Fimage-store.slidesharecdn.com%2F6451ffa0-d9d7-11e2-8c62-22000aa5108a-large.jpg",
            "title": "efry 375x563.jpg"
          },
          "id": "s5753549213216563203",
          "source": {"serviceProvider": {"name": "LINKEDIN"}},
          "timestamp": 1371752994586,
          "visibility": {"code": "anyone"}
        }}
      },
      "updateKey": "UNIU-c3858-5753549072199860224-SHARE",
      "updateType": "CMPY"
    },
    {
      "isCommentable": true,
      "isLikable": true,
      "isLiked": false,
      "numLikes": 0,
      "timestamp": 1371740602412,
      "updateComments": {"_total": 0},
      "updateContent": {
        "company": {
          "id": 3858,
          "name": "Informatica"
        },
        "companyJobUpdate": {
          "action": {"code": "created"},
          "job": {
            "company": {
              "id": 3858,
              "name": "Informatica"
            },
            "description": "Our Team The Core Technology Group (CTG) is the innovation hub within Informatica that is...",
            "id": 6133818,
            "locationDescription": "Austin, TX",
            "position": {"title": "z/OS Software Engineer, Core Technology Group (CTG), Change Data Capture "},
            "siteJobRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/jobs?viewJob=&jobId=6133818"}
          }
        }
      },
      "updateKey": "UNIU-c3858-5753497095709401088-FOLLOW_CMPY",
      "updateType": "CMPY"
    },
    {
      "isCommentable": true,
      "isLikable": true,
      "isLiked": false,
      "numLikes": 0,
      "timestamp": 1371655635134,
      "updateComments": {"_total": 0},
      "updateContent": {
        "company": {
          "id": 3858,
          "name": "Informatica"
        },
        "companyJobUpdate": {
          "action": {"code": "created"},
          "job": {
            "company": {
              "id": 3858,
              "name": "Informatica"
            },
            "description": "Our Company Informatica Corporation is the world\u2019s number one independent provider of data...",
            "id": 6116645,
            "locationDescription": "San Francisco Bay Area",
            "position": {"title": "Senior Salesforce Business Analyst, Customer Support Applications "},
            "siteJobRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/jobs?viewJob=&jobId=6116645"}
          }
        }
      },
      "updateKey": "UNIU-c3858-5753140717107044352-FOLLOW_CMPY",
      "updateType": "CMPY"
    },
    {
      "isCommentable": true,
      "isLikable": true,
      "isLiked": false,
      "numLikes": 0,
      "timestamp": 1371654686227,
      "updateComments": {"_total": 0},
      "updateContent": {
        "company": {
          "id": 3858,
          "name": "Informatica"
        },
        "companyJobUpdate": {
          "action": {"code": "created"},
          "job": {
            "company": {
              "id": 3858,
              "name": "Informatica"
            },
            "description": "Our Company Informatica is the world\u2019s number one independent provider of data integration...",
            "id": 6116458,
            "locationDescription": "San Francisco Bay Area",
            "position": {"title": "Senior Solutions Marketing Manager"},
            "siteJobRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/jobs?viewJob=&jobId=6116458"}
          }
        }
      },
      "updateKey": "UNIU-c3858-5753136737098412032-FOLLOW_CMPY",
      "updateType": "CMPY"
    },
    {
      "isCommentable": true,
      "isLikable": true,
      "isLiked": false,
      "numLikes": 0,
      "timestamp": 1371653375496,
      "updateComments": {"_total": 0},
      "updateContent": {
        "company": {
          "id": 3858,
          "name": "Informatica"
        },
        "companyJobUpdate": {
          "action": {"code": "created"},
          "job": {
            "company": {
              "id": 3858,
              "name": "Informatica"
            },
            "description": "Our Company  Informatica is the world\u2019s number one independent provider of data integration...",
            "id": 6116145,
            "locationDescription": "San Francisco Bay Area",
            "position": {"title": "Software Architect (Backend), Informatica Cloud Job"},
            "siteJobRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/jobs?viewJob=&jobId=6116145"}
          }
        }
      },
      "updateKey": "UNIU-c3858-5753131245005455360-FOLLOW_CMPY",
      "updateType": "CMPY"
    },
    {
      "isCommentable": true,
      "isLikable": true,
      "isLiked": false,
      "numLikes": 0,
      "timestamp": 1371653316689,
      "updateComments": {"_total": 0},
      "updateContent": {
        "company": {
          "id": 3858,
          "name": "Informatica"
        },
        "companyJobUpdate": {
          "action": {"code": "created"},
          "job": {
            "company": {
              "id": 3858,
              "name": "Informatica"
            },
            "description": "Our Company  Informatica Corporation (NASDAQ: INFA) is the world\u2019s number one independent...",
            "id": 6116139,
            "locationDescription": "Redwood City",
            "position": {"title": "Staff Software Engineer, Core Technology Group (Data Engine)"},
            "siteJobRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/jobs?viewJob=&jobId=6116139"}
          }
        }
      },
      "updateKey": "UNIU-c3858-5753130992839716864-FOLLOW_CMPY",
      "updateType": "CMPY"
    },
    {
      "isCommentable": true,
      "isLikable": true,
      "isLiked": false,
      "numLikes": 0,
      "timestamp": 1371653253372,
      "updateComments": {"_total": 0},
      "updateContent": {
        "company": {
          "id": 3858,
          "name": "Informatica"
        },
        "companyJobUpdate": {
          "action": {"code": "created"},
          "job": {
            "company": {
              "id": 3858,
              "name": "Informatica"
            },
            "description": "Our Company  Informatica Corporation (NASDAQ: INFA) is the world\u2019s number one independent...",
            "id": 6116123,
            "locationDescription": "Redwood City, Ca.",
            "position": {"title": "Senior Software Engineer, Core Technology Group (Data Engine)"},
            "siteJobRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/jobs?viewJob=&jobId=6116123"}
          }
        }
      },
      "updateKey": "UNIU-c3858-5753130734822883328-FOLLOW_CMPY",
      "updateType": "CMPY"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried with Gson. I already use linkedin-j. Is it possible to reuse the functionality of that. It already has the schema for that json but it is an interface. How would i reuse this?

Comment: can you show us the schema?

Comment: Quick search.. go to http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Comment: What do you mean by reuse the functionality? Also reduce the json string and keep only the required part, skip the repeating part.

Comment: @tala it is in linkedin-j.jar

Comment: @NarendraPathai I want to use that schema already in jar but it is an interface

Comment: The interface that you are referring to will have some concrete implementations. And i found out that the schema impl classes are public in linkedin-j api. So you can see the answer of @shreyanshjogi for the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); // your required gson jar 
MyType target = new MyType();
 String json = gson.toJson(target); // serializes target to Json
 MyType target2 = gson.fromJson(json, MyType.class); // deserializes json into target2
```

Mytype will be your user defined object